# I am trying to refresh a sidebar.php in wordpress on a form submit

Tags: wordpress, refresh, sidebar

I am trying to refresh a sidebar.php in wordpress on a form submit (that is in a widget on the sidebar.php).

I have video on the page and if the entire page refreshes, the video has to play from the beginning.

I need a solution to simply refresh the sidebar.php when someone submits the form ... I am not an expert php programmer so simple is best!

btw. I am using formidable plugin for the form.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for ajax!

Now, you could do it from scratch, but that would be unnecessarily painful. Instead, I recommend including jquery into your page by adding this into your header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(which uses the latest version, which is hosted on google)

Now that you have jquery loaded, there are many easy ways to submit your data without interrupting the flow of things. Here is how I would do it (I am assuming that you are using method="post"):

1. Change your `<input type="submit" >` into a `<button>`, so clicking on it doesn't trigger the built-in form submit (which would interrupt your video).
2. Set the id attribute of your button to something so that you can reference it easily like `<button id="mysubmitbutton">`. (While you are at it, give id attributes to all the form fields you care about if you have not already so that you can reference them easily as well, like `<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName">` instead of just `<input type="text" name="firstName">`)
3. Inside the `<head>` portion of your website, add some code that looks like something like this:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//makes it so that it goes after the html document is ready for it

$(document).ready(function() {

   //this ties a onclick event to your button you made

   $("#mysubmitbutton").click(function(){

    //when the button is clicked, it will asychronously post to where you want it to

      $.post("urlthatwasinyouractionequalsattribute.php", 

      { 

         //put all your post variables here, referencing the ids you made earlier

         firstName: $("#firstName").val(), 

         time: $("#time").val() //be sure you don't have a trailing comma on the last one

      },

      function(data) {

        //data is whatever the other website sends back. do whatever you want here...

        alert("Result: " + data);

      });

   });

});

</script>
```

---

Fire it up and it should work. Obviously, you will need to change the values so that it matches your form, etc.

Hope that helps! Please mark as answer if it did.

Comment: This is exciting! However I am not using the method="post". I am using a plugin to create my forms, called formidable.

Comment: Formidable uses shortode an I have not accessed the submit button directly. Will the rest of your solution work to refresh the sdebar

Comment: Can you see the source code? If so, please post it. You may end up having to abandon formidible and just go to straight-up code to have the functionality that you want (if that is an option for you).